# Validation of an email input in html5 within Razor application

Tags: regex, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a `razor` application in which i'd like to add an email validation in a view

```
  <td><input type="text" name="mail" placeholder="me@example.com" required autofocus title="" pattern="/^[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/"/> </td>
```

but here I got this syntactic error

`"[" Is not valid at the start of a block of code. Only identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid.`

What is the issue ? How can i fix it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try escape the @ with @@.

if not, put it in "{" or "(" and check.

It can be done 2 ways:

Render the "@" through razor:

```
<input type="email" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9._+-]+@("@")[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,9}$">
```

With a HTML encode:

```
<input type="email" pattern="^[a-zA-Z0-9._+-]+&#64;[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,9}$">
```

Comment: info@dot.swiss disagrees. "A TLD is 4 letters at most" was valid in 2001. It's not 2001 anymore. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains

Comment: That was not my point. "{2,4} throws out a lot of valid addresses" was.

Comment: yeah i accept. but that's not the context at all. updated to 9 incase if you want info@dot.swissbank

Comment: Technically, `root@localhost` is a valid email address. Or, `jpaugh@internal-server` But at that point, there's almost nothing to validate.